# Detect change in other column based on the value of the first column in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

```
transaction_id   vendor_id    currency
     1101           201          USD
     1102           202          EUR
     1103           203          CHF
     1104           202          EUR
     1105           204          HUF
     *1106          202          USD
     *1107          204          USD
```

I have table with three columns and there are list of transaction with two last transactions (1106 and 1107) with the `vendor_id` of `202` and `204` have the previous default currency respectively in EUR and HUF. However, in the last transaction those two vendor have **wrong currency** in their last record. The preferred outcome is to print those two transactions with wrong currency.

How can I detect the wrong currency and print those transaction in PHP (the table is from the database MySQL and the table name is `table_transaction`)?

Comment: If we had 1108, 203, USD , how would we know which row was 'wrong'?

Comment: Through the vendor_id default currency (first value in the column) of 203 is CHF.

Comment: So the first value for a given vendor is always correct?

Comment: Yes, the first entry of each vendor_id basically the default value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the following...

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS my_table;

CREATE TABLE my_table
(transaction_id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY
,vendor_id INT NOT NULL
,currency CHAR(3) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO my_table VALUES
(1101,201,'USD'),
(1102,202,'EUR'),
(1103,203,'CHF'),
(1104,202,'EUR'),
(1105,204,'HUF'),
(1106,202,'USD'),
(1107,204,'USD');

SELECT a.* 
  FROM my_table a
  LEFT 
  JOIN 
     ( SELECT x.*
         FROM my_table x 
         JOIN
            ( SELECT MIN(transaction_id) transaction_id 
                FROM my_table 
               GROUP 
                  BY vendor_id
            ) y
           ON y.transaction_id = x.transaction_id
     ) b 
    ON b.vendor_id = a.vendor_id 
   AND b.currency = a.currency
 WHERE b.transaction_id IS NULL;

 +----------------+-----------+----------+
 | transaction_id | vendor_id | currency |
 +----------------+-----------+----------+
 |           1106 |       202 | USD      |
 |           1107 |       204 | USD      |
 +----------------+-----------+----------+
```

To understand what's going on here, just break the query down into its constituent parts and add `b.transaction_id` to the SELECT...

Part 'y'

```
SELECT MIN(transaction_id) transaction_id 
  FROM my_table 
 GROUP 
    BY vendor_id
```

This bit grabs the first transaction_id for each vendor. This works because transaction_id is the PRIMARY KEY.

We then join this result back to the source table, to get the other columns corresponding to that transaction_id (specifically `currency`, in this case):

```
   SELECT x.*
     FROM my_table x 
     JOIN
        ( SELECT MIN(transaction_id) transaction_id 
            FROM my_table 
           GROUP 
              BY vendor_id
        ) y
       ON y.transaction_id = x.transaction_id
```

Finally, we OUTER JOIN all of the above back to the table again, in order to get rows which DON'T satisfy the criteria (`b.vendor_id = a.vendor_id AND b.currency = a.currency WHERE b.transaction_id IS NULL`).

```
SELECT a.* 
     , b.transaction_id
  FROM my_table a
  LEFT 
  JOIN 
     ( SELECT x.*
         FROM my_table x 
         JOIN
            ( SELECT MIN(transaction_id) transaction_id 
                FROM my_table 
               GROUP 
                  BY vendor_id
            ) y
           ON y.transaction_id = x.transaction_id
     ) b 
    ON b.vendor_id = a.vendor_id 
   AND b.currency = a.currency;

+----------------+-----------+----------+----------------+
| transaction_id | vendor_id | currency | transaction_id |
+----------------+-----------+----------+----------------+
|           1101 |       201 | USD      |           1101 |
|           1102 |       202 | EUR      |           1102 |
|           1103 |       203 | CHF      |           1103 |
|           1104 |       202 | EUR      |           1102 |
|           1105 |       204 | HUF      |           1105 |
|           1106 |       202 | USD      |           NULL | <-- We only  want
|           1107 |       204 | USD      |           NULL | <-- these 'NULL' rows
+----------------+-----------+----------+----------------+
```

Comment: Waah this is what I am looking, thank you! Anyway, the where clause is the key. Could you kindly elaborate?